# Powershell download entire directory contents

Tags: powershell, recursion, download

http://gisdata.nd.gov/NAIP/2012/zGeoTiffs/

I would like to download the entire directory, each link contains another series of links.

This is what I have so far and it works sort of (brings back a 200 status), but it doesn't download

```
import-module bitstransfer
invoke-webrequest “http://gisdata.nd.gov/NAIP/2012/zGeoTiffs/”
select -exp links|where{$_.href -like "*.tif"}
select -exp href|foreach{start-bitstransfer $_ F:\GIS\2012GeoTiff}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless PowerShell is a requirement, using [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) would be an easier way to mirror something like that:

```
wget --mirror --no-parent --accept=tif http://gisdata.nd.gov/NAIP/2012/zGeoTiffs/
```

Comment: Great!  I didn't mirror, just used a recursive download and excluded *.html files, but thank you very much! this has been a great resource!